# Javascript error in IE8 with the latest version of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, cdn

I have developed a booking engine which works with the very latest versions of jQuery & jQuery UI (via the google CDN)

It works fine in most browsers however Internet Explorer 8 returns the following Java error:

```
Description:Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'
Source:http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
Line:3
```

Can anyone suggest a workaround that will not break anything in the modern browsers too :)

Comment: is it IE8 or IE9? (title says one, question text says the other)

Comment: What's the code causing the error?

Comment: Very sorry - its early.. its IE8 with the issue. It is Line 3 within the jQuery script causing the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support `canvas`, you can simulate it though with a JavaScript library called [explorercanvas](https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/).

IE9 does, if you are using IE9 and you get that error you are likely in a different browser mode/document mode, provided you are calling is on a `canvas` object. Press F12 to open the developer tools and select the IE9 browser mode and document mode.

These can change if you have an old of invalid doctype declaration, make sure you're including the HTML5 doctype as the first line on your document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Cheers the excanvas did the trick! 2 second fix.. just how I like em!